# Hide a part of an image on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is what I'm trying to do :
Have 2 divs one under the other. The bottom one is displaying an image and the up one is let's say white.

On hover, I want the white one to hide so that we can see the one under, with like its opacity down to 0 so it's transparent.

The things is, it should only show a part of that div with a transparent gradient circle around it, following the mouse's course.

[image]

[image]

Don't mind the white rectangle, it's about the background : the UP div would be a white fullscreen div, whereas the bottom one would be the sky, and when hovering with the mouse we would only see a part of the sky.

Do you guys have any idea on how I could do that, using HTML, css and/or JQuery? :/

Comment: Erm... inner shadow of white + opacity 0.5? There, I gave a hint. Go forth and write code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
The thing is, I don't know to what I could apply those properties, since it should follow the user's mouse...

Answer (score 0):

one solution would be using a white PNG with a transparent gradient hole in it as the background of the upper div

then with onHover="script..." you set the position of the upper div

both divs must have absolute positioning so one gets on the top of the other